# Set record type when creating an object without using RecordTypeId

Tags: record, type

I have a custom object with two record types, How can I set the record type using the record type name when creating a new object record??

Without using the RecordTypeId is possible?? I think is not a good practice Isn't it?

A lot of thanks

Comment: You profile has default recordTypeId, it would be set when you create record

Comment: And how I set or change the recordtype using the recordtype name? Is that possible

Comment: Why do you want to use RecordType Name instead of Id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not any way (at least, not that I know of) to completely take the recordTypeId out of the equation, but there is a way to use the record type's name to get at the appropriate Id.

Specifically, the SObject's "describe" information, via [the DescribeSObjectResult class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) provides several methods to get record type information.

Probably the most common way to use this is something like this

```java
Id myRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('My Record Type Label').getRecordTypeId();
// Schema.SObjectType.Account gets you the DescribeSObjectResult (for the Account SObject in this case)
// (You could use Account.SObjectType.getDescribe() instead to get the DescribeSObjectResult)
// getRecordTypeInfosByName() gets you a Map<String, RecordTypeInfo> where the keys of the map
//   are the record type labels (i.e. keep any spaces in the name as spaces instead of underscores)
// getRecordTypeId() gets you, well...the record type's Id
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the name directly without a describe call:

```
Object__c record = new Object__c(Name='Demo', RecordType=new RecordType(Name='SomeType'));
```

Note that this technique only works if the record type game is globally unique in your org across all sObject types.

Otherwise, you can, and should, use a describe call to get the Id dynamically, as noted in the other answer.